# Oracle truncating column

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, sql-insert, truncation

I have the following query.

```
insert into ORDER_INFO(ORDINF_PK,ORDINF_LGNDET_PK_FK,MEDIA_TYPE,ORDINF_MUSIC_FK,DAT)
values (1,1,'Music',21,TO_DATE('14-OCT-2015','DD-MON-YYYY'));

insert into ORDER_INFO(ORDINF_PK,ORDINF_LGNDET_PK_FK,MEDIA_TYPE,ORDINF_MUSIC_FK,ORDINF_SERIES_FK,DAT)
values (2,2,'Series',71,23,TO_DATE('07-NOV-2015','DD-MON-YYYY'));
```

however when I do:

```
select * from ORDER_INFO;
```

I get:

```
truncating (as requested) before column ORDINF_SERIES_FK

truncating (as requested) before column ORDINF_MOVIES_FK

 ORDINF_PK ORDINF_LGNDET_PK_FK           MEDIA_TYPE ORDINF_MUSIC_FK      DAT
---------- ------------------- -------------------- --------------- ---------
     1                       1                Music              21 14-NOV-14
     2                       2               Series              71 07-NOV-15
```

I understand that it is truncating ORDINF_MOVIES_FK because there is no entry in that column, but why is it truncating the column ORDINF_SERIES_FK?

Comment: I am very very new to SQL (a few hours), so I don't know what you mean by  "How are you running that SQL?". I am running it from terminal using an SSH. Does that answer the question? I am using sqlplus.

Comment: maybe you can try with 
`COLUMN ORDINF_MOVIES_FK CLEAR`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue, I did this.

```
set wrap on;
set pagesize 50000;
set linesize 120;
```

link here: http://www.anattatechnologies.com/q/2012/01/sqlplus-pagesize-and-linesize/

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention - both rows inserted and ARE in the database, so INSERT succeeded.
The warning you get is a warning from SQL*Plus program that means that column is display not with full width (maybe the definition of column is long and SQL*Plus decides to show column shorter because data you have in there is short).
You do not need to worry about this in any case.

See [this](http://gerardnico.com/wiki/sqlplus/wrap) link for more explanation about SQL*Plus wrap.